# MongoDB - Update a field in an object of an array with multiple filter conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have the following document in my database :

```
{
    "_id" : MainId,
    "subdoc" : [
        {
            "_id" : SubdocId,
            "userid" : "someid",
            "toupdate": false,
        },
        {
            "_id" : SubdocId2,
            "userid" : "someid2",
            "toupdate": false,
        }       
    ],
    "extra" : [
        "extraid1",
        "extraid2"
    ]
}
```

How can I update the subdocument SubdocId2 where the id (SubdocId2) must match and either SubdocId2's userid is "someid2" OR value "extraid1" exists in "extra"?

The farthest I got is:

```
db.coll.update({
"subdoc._id":"SubdocId2", {
    $or: ["extra":{$in:["extraid1"]}, "subdoc.userid":"someid2"]
    }
}, {"subdoc.$.toupdate":true})
```

Maybe I forgot to quote up something, but I get an error `(SyntaxError: invalid property id)`

Comment: SubdocId2 is a string?

Comment: Technically it's an ObjectId.

Comment: ok, so in your update you need to use an ObjectId. "subdoc._id": ObjectId('SubdocId2'). You're using a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.coll.update(
    {
        $and: [{ "subdoc._id": SubdocId2 }, {
            $or: [{ "extra": { $in: ["extraid1"] } },
            { "subdoc.userid": "someid2" }]
        }] // subdoc._id && (extra || subdoc.userid)
    }, { $set: { "subdoc.$.toupdate": true } })
```

In your query there are couple of syntax issues & also if you don't use `$set` in your update part - it replace the entire document with `"subdoc.$.toupdate": true`. Of course if you're using `mongoose` that's different scenario as mongoose will internally does add `$set` but when executing in shell or any client you need to specify `$set`. Also if `SubdocId2` is `ObjectId()` you need to convert `string` to `ObjectId()` in code before querying database.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!